# how to show jquery rating in html <list> tag in while loop using multiple tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-lists, rating

i want to show rating of each item or name of company with company name (driven from another table in database) in "li" tag of html (transporters.php). I have got the rating for each company page individually (transporters2.php) but i want to get all the ratings of all the companies or items in "li" tab so user can overview it and after clicking an "li" item it will show the profile of company "transporters2.php". Here are my two files **transporters.php** and **transporters2.php** and also their snapshots.
[transporters.php and transporters2.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yvIu.png) ,[Mydatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKPz4.png)

**Note:** *Both files are working correctly there is no syntax error, if an error occurs that might be occurred while posting the question thanks.*

**Transporters.php**

```
<?php
include "header.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/rating.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rating.js"></script><title>Transporters</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/bin/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/bin/css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/bin/font-awesome/css/font
awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link href="../css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
<!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h1 class="page-header">Transporters
<small> Companies</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">Transporters</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Content Row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"><?php
require("Config.php");


$sql =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transporters");
?>
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql) )
{
$cid=$row['CompanyID'];
?>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<li><div class="product" style="font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;margin: 0 auto 40px auto;width: 71px;height: 4px;margin-right: 75%;">
       <div id="<?php echo $cid ?>" class="ratings" style="border: 1px solid #CCC;overflow: visible;padding: 10px;position: relative;width: 182px;height: 47px;float: left;margin-left: -195px;"><div class="star_1  ratings_stars ratings_vote"></div><div class="star_2  ratings_stars ratings_vote"></div><div class="star_3  ratings_stars ratings_vote"></div><div class="star_4 ratings_stars ratings_blank"></div><div class="star_5 ratings_stars ratings_blank"></div>
      </div>
 <a href='transporters2.php?CompanyID=<?php echo $cid;?>'><?php print $row['CompanyName']; ?>
        </a></div>
  </li>     
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}//end of while loop
?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function sendcompanyname()
{
var x=  document.getElementById("cpn").value;
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

**Transporters2.php**

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1") or die("unable to connect");
include("header.php");
$cname;
if(isset($_GET['CompanyID'])){
$CompanyID = $_GET['CompanyID'];
$get_name= "SELECT * from `transporters` where `CompanyID`='$CompanyID'";
$run_name= mysqli_query($db,$get_name);
while($row_name=mysqli_fetch_array($run_name)){
$cname = $row_name['CompanyName'];}
}
include("settings.php");
connect();
$ids=array(1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/rating.css" />
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rating.js"></script>-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ratings_stars').hover(
// Handles the mouseover
function() {
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
$(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
},
// Handles the mouseout
function(){
$(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
}
);
//send ajax request to rate.php
$('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function(){
var id=$(this).parent().attr("id");
var num=$(this).attr("class");
var poststr="id="+id+"&stars="+num;
$.ajax({url:"../bin/rate.php",cache:0,data:poststr,success:function(result){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=result;}
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++)
{
$rating_tableName = 'ratings';
$id=$CompanyID;
$q="SELECT total_votes, total_value FROM $rating_tableName WHERE id=$id";
$r=mysql_query($q);
if(!$r) echo mysql_error();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
$v=$row['total_votes'];
$tv=$row['total_value'];
$rat=$tv/$v;
}
$id=$CompanyID;
$j=$id;
echo'<div class="product">
Rate Item '.$j.'
<div id="rating_'.$id.'" class="ratings">';
for($k=1;$k<6;$k++){
if($rat+1>$k)$class="star_".$k."ratings_stars ratings_vote";
else $class="star_".$k." ratings_stars ratings_blank";
echo '<div class="'.$class.'"></div>';
}
echo' <div class="total_votes"><p class="voted"> Rating
<strong>'.@number_format($rat).'</strong>/5 ('.$v. 'vote(s) cast) 
</div>
</div></div>';}
?>
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h2 class="page-header"><?php echo $cname;?></h2>
</div>
<!--<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
<div class="panel-heading">
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>Show Drivers</h4>
<p>Show drivers of this company.</p>
<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()" class="btn btn
primary">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
<div class="panel-heading">
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
<i class="fa fa-support fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>Show routes</h4>
<p>check which routes are following this company...</p>
<a href="routes.php?CompanyID=<?php echo $CompanyID;?>" class="btn btn
primary">show routes</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
<div class="panel-heading">
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
<i class="fa fa-database fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>Schedule</h4>
<p>Check the timings of journey.</p>
<a href="quotations.php" class="btn btn-primary">Show Schedule</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
<div class="panel-heading">
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
<i class="fa fa-database fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>Show Drivers Positions</h4>
<p>Check the positions of all drivers.</p>
<a href="positions.php" class="btn btn-primary">Show Drivers
Positions</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!---END Page Content--> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: have u seen the snapshots ? i want to get the rating from database in transporters.php in the snapshot that ratings are hardcoded in transporters.php

Comment: Did you want us to code that for you? Or did you want to share what you have tried and the problems you had making it work?

Comment: i just want to know the logic or any way or idea how can i do it.. i am a student and this is my semester project...

Comment: First show whatever you have tried to accomplish this.